# Who is the huge soldier among Zod's retinue in Man of Steel?

Tags: dc, superman, character-identification, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

In *Man of Steel*, when Zod attacks the Council, we get a glimpse on some of his soldiers. One of them, seems to be a **physically huge guy** (I don't think it is a matter of perspective in the screen)

[image]

Can be seen really well in the video here (min 0:15)

It called my attention due to his size, but I'm not that familiar with the Superman mythos. **Is he supposed to be any of the well known Kryptonian enemies of Superman (Non, Quex-Ul, etc.)?**

Comment: Doesn't he get in direct combat with superman at the end of the movie?

Comment: @EricSSH, either that or he picks Zod or Faora after a combat with Superman, IIRC. You are right, he is seen again in the movie. Maybe I can get better pictures from those scenes. Thanks.

Comment: if your are talking about the tall big guy the answer below is correct. Stats -- Gender - Male - Height - 9'3" - Weight - 395lbs -Eyes - Brown - Hair - Brown

Comment: He is the one with Faora fighting Superman in Smallville. He also picks up Faora and carries her onto the ship after a missile knocks her out at the end of that battle.

Comment: 8'3" would be a more accurate height.

Comment: One of your images was dead, so I cut it out. [See here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10694/70236)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This is [Nam-Ek](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Nam-Ek)**

> Nam-Ek was born on the distant planet Krypton as a genetically engineered soldier without a speaking ability, later joining the ranks of Krypton's Military under the leadership of General Zod whom Nam-Ek answered only to. Nam-Ek was a test subject of a test to mix the DNA of Kryptonians and animals know as Randor. The test caused Nam-Ek to grow multiple feet taller and develop superhuman strength even while in Krypton's environment.

It is also my understanding he is completely CGI in the movie, can't confirm it though.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if the person who named him is a Dragon Ball fan...

Comment: I can't find Nam-Ek, "Big/Tall Kryptonian" or anything of the like in the film credits on IMDB, so he may well be a full CGI creation. Getting hard to tell these days, ain't it? I assumed it was an actor enhanced with CGI but maybe not.

Comment: @Omegacron that was my assumption also.

Comment: http://movies.cosmicbooknews.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/600_wide/wysiwyg_imageupload/1/mo-cap-man-antiobiotic-man.jpg - He's a CGI character. He was animated using motion capture

Comment: Gracias. That was my problem with IMDB too. I thought he might be the same guy as in Superman II (Non), but I had no luck with my research.

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-IgCfo2m-dAs/TlS4IQcGpkI/AAAAAAAAARE/1kFxDUR6GoA/s640/man+of+steel+superman.jpg - Mo-cap man.

Answer (score 4):

This could also be [Tor-An](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Tor-An), a large Kryptonian played by stuntman [**Richard Cetrone**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0149150/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t18#actor). He can be seen without his helmet in a couple of scenes, and is a fairly tall guy (6'4"). If it IS Cetrone, obviously his height was enhanced with CGI in post-production.

Here is his first appearance, when Zod lands on Jor-El's landing pad during the Krypton battle. That's him in the center background:

[image]

He can be seen again briefly when Zod is exploring the Kryptonian colony world:

[image]

Cetrone is probably known to most genre fans as "Pierce" in the [Underworld franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_(film_series)). He was also the stunt-double for Tony Stark in [Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_(2008_film)), as well as the stunt double for Ben Affleck in the upcoming "[Batman vs. Superman: Dawn of Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice)". While looking this up, I learned he was also the lead antagonist (Big Daddy Mars) in "[Ghosts of Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_of_Mars)" as well as the Merman (AND the Werewolf) in "[Cabin in the Woods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cabin_in_the_Woods)". So even if the big guy isn't Tor-An, it may still be Cetrone doing the motion capture work for the character.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

That was Sciencist NON....the mentor /ex-friend of Jor-El. His' brain was altered so he couldn't speak by the Science Council; because he was the first to discovered the planet Kypton was dying. Try to go public with it .On early the Head Sciencist El didn't believe him ; he watched his' ex- mentor/friend be permanently silienced forever....Non's last words  was revenge on the bloodline of the House of El.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is there any evidence to support what you've said in this answer? If so, please [edit] the answer to include it. Evidence goes a long way around here.